# Java keytool: Inserting a private key into an X.509 certificate

Tags: java, key, private, keytool, x509

Does Java's keytool have the ability to export an X.509 certificate with a private key in it?

I am considering a scenario in which users generate a certificate (with the private key in it) and supply it to a signing tool. The signing tool uses the private key in the certificate to sign a target file. Eventually, the private key is removed from the certificate and the cert is attached to the target file for distribution.

Comment: An X509 certificate does not have a private key.

Comment: That was my initial understanding too. It turns out though, that .NET has a cert creation tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.80).aspx) that has options to include the private key with the X.509 cert.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet, so I'll use this form:
Usually one uses PKCS #12 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS#12 for storing a certificate with its private Key. Also, one can store a public/private key pair in a PCKS #8 Container and ship the certificate separately.

If you're interested, i think i have some java code samples for PKCS #12 storage.

Also, the open source Java Certificate Authority EJBCA (http://www.ejbca.org/) is a great source for examples.

Comment: since i still can't comment, i wanted to add something: The cert creation tool you referenced does NOT create a x.509 cert containing a private key, however, it creates a proprietary unprotected *.snk file containing the cert and the private key. They, too, recommend the use of a container to store cert & key.

Comment: Got it. Reading up on PKCS#12 makes me realize that this would be the format used by keystore files (e.g., Java keystore) that allow the storage of private key and cert pairs in the same file. Thanks for your response. I will read more about this on the website you referenced in your previous response.

Answer (score 1):

Private keys generated are never used or shared by others for any purposes.
Signing tools that I know would use their own private key to generate their signature to certify your public key. For e.g. you generate a key pair using keytool and submit a CSR to a CA. CA would use their own pvt key to stamp their signature on your certificate.

Comment: that named PEM, file that contains both private and public key

Answer (score 1):

The *keytool* (the commandline executable) does not have the option to export private keys. But you may use the JSA-API to do it programmatically (haven't tried, though).

Answer (score 1):

Keys and their signed certificates are often stored in keystore containers such as PKCS12 or Java's JKS. It is also possible to extract certificates and keys into PEM format files for use in apps like Apache HTTPD.

To extract certs and keys from a JKS file it's necessary to convert it to PKCS12 format file before extracting the certs with openssl:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.pkcs12 -deststoretype pkcs12
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.pkcs12 -out mycert.crt -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.pkcs12 -out mykey.key -nocerts
```